# How can I separate a string so that the first words are in one variable and the last word is in another?

Tags: php

I have a string that looks like this: `This is a sample string`

and I want to separate the sting so that the first words are in one variable and the last word is in another. So:

```
$beginning = "This is a sample"
$lasword = "string"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @Dagon ...and then pop off the last one and implode the rest back together...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @Michael ... and then go down the pub and have a beer ...

Comment: @Dagon You mean you're ready for your first beer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  One easy way (though not necessarily the most efficient) is to make an array by splitting on the spaces, remove the last one, and then stick the rest back together into a string via [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [`array_pop()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
// All words into an array
$words = explode(" ", "This is a string");
// Remove the last one into $last
$last = array_pop($words);
// And stick the first words back together into a string
$rest = implode(" ", $words);
echo $rest;
echo $last;
```

A bunch of substring operations making use of `strrpos()` to find the last occurrence of the space and `substr()` or `str_split()` to chop it up are likely to be more efficient, but honestly I would be more likely to use this method unless performance was really an issue.

Comment: I didn't know about array_pop()! This is a great answer.

Comment: @Jared ... and learn its cousins `array_shift(), array_unshift(), array_push()` (though using the `[] =` array append language construct is usually preferable to `array_push()`

Comment: @Michael I learned last night that array_push is best for multiple inputs, while array[] is best for a single input. Gotta say of all the web development aspects arrays are one of the most fascinating (behind sql).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about php, but in other languages we use substring functions.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is a link to php reference about the substring function.

Comment: starting an answer like that does not inspire much confidence :-) I'm not a doctor, but I suggest amputation of the head for that runny nose you have.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could split the string and then access them

$mystring = explode(" ", "This is a sample string");

and then access them

echo $mystring[0] //This

to get the last word you would need to get the length first of the $mystring
$len = strlen($mystring);

echo $mystring[$len]; //string